# Invoke a javascript on a web page through python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I want to invoke some javascript on a certain page through python. 
The Js is opening another page and would like to get it.

```
javascript:(function()%7Bdocument.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='https://members.cj.com/member/publisherBookmarklet.js?version=1';%7D)();
```

Whats the best way todo so? I started to play with [ScrapyJs+Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash) and but didnt manage to get it working. I am on the right path ?

Comment: Can't you bypass the JS by figuring out what request it does to fetch the other page?